# lowering draw calls by not drawing things that are not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was searching for methods to optimise my game.

I was thinking if there is a way to not draw the objects that are in the camera view but are not visible to the viewer?

The thing is that i need to lower my draw calls and at any given time, there are at least 12 game objects that are not visible to the camera. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *occlusion culling* and it's a [built-in feature in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html). In order to lower the number of draw calls there are some more techniques interesting for your problem:

- [Frustum culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Camera.html)
- [Layer specific culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html)
- Texture atlasses i.e. several different objects share the same material
- Static and dynamic [draw call batching](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html)
- [LOD](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html) (level of detail)

Answer (score 3):

Kay is right to reduce draw call of objects which are not visible you need to use occulusion culling,

and if you still wants to reduce more draw calls you should use Free unity plugin "**Draw Call Minimizer**" by Purdyjo available on asset store.
and here is its [unity video tutorial](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-i-reduce-draw-calls-from-69-to-12.html)